# How relative paths to .war work?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, path

I have a Spring Boot app that I tried deploying to a .war to run it from a Tomcat server.

Before this I was deploying to a executable .jar and everything worked perfectly.

In the app I need to read a .json file and also read a directory, their locations are given as relative. When deploying to .jar I would have the file in the same folder as the .jar. I would access it as: `./branchMap.json`. The directory would also be in the same folder as the jar and I would access it as: `./patches`.

Now when I am deploying to .war I place the app in webapps in Tomcat and I place the json file and the folder also in webapps. When I run the app it is able to read the json file, but it is not able to read the /patches folder.

Why is this happening? I have seen that Tomcat tries to load the /patches folder as a app, in is listed in the tomcat manager. How does this interfere with the app trying to read access that folder? Is there something different in the way that a app deployed to war accesses relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

Read the paches folder location from properties file and in the property file you can mention the full path of the patches folder.

Comment: this is not a solution, as I want to be able to deploy the jar on different machines

Comment: In that case you can go for centralized configuration.. For different machines you can create patches folder with same path in the centralized config server.

Comment: yes, I could do that, but my question is more about why this happens only when deploying to a war, why is an executable jar working

Comment: while running as standalone jar, the jar file location comes under classpath. So only you are not getting any issue. But while running as a jar inside a tomcat server, your apps folder under webapps/${application}/WEB-INF/classes becomes the classpath folder. So if you are keeping your files inside the specific folder(webapps/${application}/WEB-INF/classes), may be your application can read then. You can try ...